# Clone radio label and change input 'checked' property when label is clicked

Tags: jquery

I have a form with a number of `input[type='radio']` elements. When one of these is clicked I'm cloning the label of that particular element and placing its label into a  element. What I've not been able to figure out is how to do the following:

1) If the cloned label is removed (i.e. clicked) the radio input should default to `<input id="default" type="radio"/>` and the associated label of this default input should output in the header.

2) If a radio button is clicked then any clone label that is output in the header is removed and replaced by the new clone.

You can see the following pen what is happening. In short, the checked status isn't changing as intended and the labels of the clones are themselves being cloned.

[**Click me**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yXzMaZ)

Markup

```
<header>
</header>
<aside>
  <form action="">
    <input name="form" id="default" type="radio" />
    <label for="default">Default</label>
    <input name="form" id="one" type="radio" />
    <label for="one">One</label>
    <input name="form" id="two" type="radio" />
    <label for="two">Two</label>
  </form>
</aside>
```

jQuery 1.7

```
// Set active state on default radio input
$("#default").prop("checked", true);

// Clone and add / remove associated radio labels on click  
$("input").click(function() {

  var self = $(this);
  $('header label.radio-clone').remove();
  // if checked clone the radio input's label amd add to header
  if (self.prop('checked', true)) {
    self
      .next("label")
      .clone()
      .addClass("radio-clone")
      .appendTo("header");
    // add a class to associated original label (i.e. the non-cloned one)
    self.next("label").addClass("is-checked");
  } else {
    // if label in header is clicked remove from header  
    $('header label[for="' + self.attr('id') + '"]').remove();
    // remove class on the original label
    self.next("label").removeClass("is-checked");
    // revert checked property to false on all radio inputs  
    self.prop("checked", false).addClass('test1');
    // then add checked true to the default radio input
    $("#default").prop("checked", true).addClass('test2');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution of sorts. Given that a value will be displayed at all times for the radio inputs I simply clone the label and avoid any events on the clone. I'd still love to know how to achieve my initial goal (I think I'd possibly have to drop the `if` and go with a separate click event on the original input and another on the cloned label) so if anyone has a solution please fire away.

Here is the pared back solution.

[Click me](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZyXJGP)

```
// On page load set active state on default radio input and clone label to header 
$("#default").prop("checked", true);
$("#default")
  .next("label")
  .clone(true, true)
  .prepend("Blah: ")
  .addClass("radio-clone")
  .appendTo("header");

// On click clone and add / remove associated radio labels on click
$("input").click(function() {
  var self = $(this);
  $("header label.radio-clone").remove();
  // if checked clone the radio input's label amd add to header
  if (self.prop("checked", true)) {
    self
      .next("label")
      .clone(true, true)
      .prepend("Blah: ")
      .addClass("radio-clone")
      .appendTo("header");
    // add a class to associated original label (i.e. the non-cloned one)
    $("input").next("label").removeClass("is-checked"); // remove
    self.next("label").addClass("is-checked"); // then add
  }
});
```